# update pending contributions transaction date wrong

Tags: contributions, pending

When doing a search for pending contributions and then do a batch update to completed the received date is changed to today's date. In the past version 4 this would stay as the original received date. This is causing us problems as the received date shouldn't change.

We are using CiviCRM 5.3.1 on Drupal 7

Thanks

Gareth

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Batch update using profile than including `Receive date` in your profile will actually solve your issue. There has been change in code to handle contribution fields correctly now.

The workflow does make sense when changing contribution to completed the receive date is updated to now(). The system assumes that money has come in now unless you specify the exact date.

So when you include Receive date in your profile it will be pre populated with old values and hence it won't update to now().

HTH

Pradeep